# Is it bad to send php GET request every second to feed chat system

Tags: post, get

I am developing a chat system with php ,mysqli and ajax.

I want to send request to the server to get new chat every second usign AJAX GET.

I am using SETINTERVAL every second but i get 500 internal server error

Can someone suggest or educate me on that

Answer (score 0):

As a general idea, a `500` error essentially tells that your backend has uncaught exceptions.
I would suggest looking for errors on the part of your PHP code that handles the AJAX calls.

PS: It's hard to say anything unless you share the code. Sharing code makes it easier to help.